# Python Bayesian belief network Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, bayesian-networks

Can anyone recommend a Bayesian belief network classifier implemented in Python that can generate a probability of belief based on the input of a sparse network describing a series of facts about several inter-related objects?

e.g. given the facts "X is hungry, is a monkey and eats" formulated in FOL like:

```
isHungry(x) ^ isMonkey(x) ^ eats(x,y)
```

as well as a training corpus like:

```
isHungry(a) ^ isMonkey(a) ^ eats(a,b) => true
isHungry(b) ^ ~isMonkey(b) ^ eats(b,c) => true
isMonkey(d) ^ eats(d,e) => true
isMonkey(f) ^ eats(f,g) => false
isMonkey(h) ^ ~eats(h,i) => true
isBanana(j) ^ ~eats(j,k) => true
```

I'd like to train a Bayesian belief network on the corpus, and use it to estimate the belief probability of the facts.

Note, I'm *not* talking about Naive Bayesian text classifiers.

Answer (score 2):

The [Python Bayes Network Toolbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pbnt.berlios/) would be a good starting point.

In addition, there is this more generic Bayesian inference tools package, named [bayespy](http://bayespy.org/) .

Hth.

Answer (score 1):

eBay has one open sourced, never used it though: https://github.com/eBay/bayesian-belief-networks

Answer (score 0):

The python library [bnlearn](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn) can be helpfull.
*Disclaimer: I am the author of this library*.