# What data structure should I use for sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, text, data-structures

I'm trying to make a [Bayesian Belief Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network), so that I can use it to perform [Sentiment Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis) on text. I was wondering which data structure should I use for coding it in Python? A link list? Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe someone else asked the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668744/python-bayesian-belief-network-classifier) before. Looks like there's a ready to use library that helps you here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guido wrote an [essay](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) on implementing graphs in Python using dictionaries.  He gives the following example:

> Few programming languages provide direct support for graphs as a data
> type, and Python is no exception. However, graphs are easily built out
> of lists and dictionaries. For instance, here's a simple graph (I
> can't use drawings in these columns, so I write down the graph's
> arcs):
>
> ```
> A -> B
> A -> C
> B -> C
> B -> D
> C -> D
> D -> C
> E -> F
> F -> C
> ```
>
> This graph has six nodes (A-F) and eight arcs. It can be represented by the following Python data structure:
>
> ```
> graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
>          'B': ['C', 'D'],
>          'C': ['D'],
>          'D': ['C'],
>          'E': ['F'],
>          'F': ['C']}
> ```